# Others or the others in this example

Tags: word-choice, grammar, pronouns

> The goal of ABC is to enable the doctors all around the world to share
>   and benefit from the knowledge of (the) others.
>   (meaning of other doctors all around the world)

I know that THE OTHERS is used when there is a limited count. But there is always a limited, finite count (people on the world..).
Should there be others or THE others?

Comment: Who are the others? Have you referred to them in a previous sentence? Incidentally, the sentence is ambiguous with or without the article: Do you mean other doctors (apparently) or the rest of the world (which is what the sentence means). Furthermore, the infinitive better be repeated: "to share, and **to** benefit from, " with those (optional) commas as well.

Comment: No, it's not. As I said, it does **not** mean doctors.

Comment: But what about sentences like "I have failed the exam but the others passed".

Comment: Only those who appeared for the exam with you could pass -- the rest of the world could possibly not. So it's clear.

Comment: Here, "others" does not mean ***all the rest*** of the doctors. It just means some of them. So you should use "others". If you say "I failed the exam but the others passed", it means that you were the only one failed the exam (or maybe that you were the only one of your friends who failed the exam).

Comment: And if I put "the others", would it not imply that it is related only to doctors? @Peter Shor: you mentioned 'others' twice, not sure which one is meant to be 'the others'.

Comment: Yes, my comment is ambiguous; I should have said "the others" generally means "all of the other ones" (although which total population you are referring to depends on context), while "others" means "some of the other ones". And it doesn't matter whether you say "the others" or "others"; unless it was clarified in other sentences in the paragraph, I would interpret it as meaning doctors here.

Comment: I thought that when I say "doctors...to share with the others" it is quite clear.

Comment: "doctors...to share with the others" obviously means with non-doctors, you get it? :)

Comment: Have you visited ell.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: kris: No, I do not. My native language uses 7 words for that and it is hard for me to simplify it that much. So how can I say that doctors are sharing with all other doctors around the world - using the pronoun?

Comment: Ok, what about this? People diagnosed with ALS meet once a month and benefit from the experience of the others. Would it be correct here? The rest meaning just the diagnosed people?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The** is a *definite article*. There is a discussion of that part of speech [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29).  In short, a definite article

> indicates that its noun is a particular one (or ones) identifiable to the listener

The identification of the noun usually occurs in the same sentence or in a preceding sentence.

In your example, there are no previous sentences given that might explain *which others* you are describing.  There is also no indication within the sentence itself. As such, a particular group of *others* is not identified, and the definite article *the* seems to be trying to define a particular group without indicating what that group is.

The situation would change if identifiable delimiters of *others* were provided:

> *The ABC is a coalition of all of the doctors in the world*. The goal of ABC is to enable the doctors all around the world to share and benefit from the knowledge of the others.

or

> The goal of ABC is to enable each of the doctors all around the world to share and benefit from the knowledge of the others.

As written in your example, it is not clear whether *others* refers to a subset of other doctors in the world, all the doctors in the world, or some group of others that may or may not be doctors (such as nurses, scientists).

Answer (score 0):

It might be prefeable to recast it as something like:

> The goal of ABC is to enable doctors all around the world to share and
>   benefit from each other’s knowledge.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I am interested in the use of others/the others.

Comment: In that case, most readers, I imagine, would take _the others_ to mean other doctors. _Others_ on its own would not necessarily give that meaning.